# Accessing specific key in a map that is passed to a spring JSP page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, dictionary

i am passing a TreeMap to a JSP page. The map contains as keys the days of the current or the next month. The passed data has to be rendered in the JSP page. Therefore i need a way to access the `.containsKey()` or `.containsValue()` or the `.get()` method from the map. I tried these methods but i always get an exception.

When i'm using the `.get(1)` or `.get("1")` method i eclipse shows me a `ClassCastException`

```
java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

Any ideas how to solve my problem?

Edit: The Code:

```
public TreeMap<String, String> getCalendarEntries(
    boolean showNextMonth) throws Exception{
TreeMap<String, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, String>();

// doing some stuff... 

treeMap.put("2", "someValue"); 

// ..

return treeMap;
}
```

The controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) throws Exception {
// do stuff.. 

TreeMap<String, String> treeMap = getCalendarEntries(true);

model.addAttribute("treeMap", treeMap);
return "home"
}
```

The JSP Page

```
<c:forEach var="calendarEntry" items="${calendarEntries }">
${calendarEntry.getKey()}-${calendarEntry.getValue()}
// Returns the key/value mapping
</c:forEach>

${calendarEntries.get("2")}
// returns nothing.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your map structure is like this.

```
    Map<Long,Object> map =new HashMap<Long,Object>()
    map.put(1l,"value1");
    map.put(2l,"value2");
```

But you are accessing it using `.get(1)`. here `1` is as an integer and system is trying to cast to long and it failed.

try `.get(1l)` instead of `.get(1)`

Comment: That is why i am confused. The Map is <Integer, String>. I am not using longs anywhere in the project. I switched it to <String, String> and accessed it in the JSP file via .get("2"). But it returns no value. But when i iterate with a for loop over the map i get all the values in the JSP page.

Comment: @smsnheck How you fill data to the Map

Comment: Well via the <String, String> method it works now fine. The problem was that i tried to access "2" and not "02". With the Integer one i populate the map via Integer.parseInt() method.

Comment: @smsnheck hmm.. great findings....